# SpotInstanceRequest to Instance object?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm new on ec2 python programming using boto.

I request spot instances with the method **request_spot_instances** from the connection object.
This will return a list of **SpotInstanceRequest** objects.

I need to know when my instances are running, so i'd like to use methods like **instance.update()** and **instance.state** attribute.

But how can I transform my request object to instances objects ?

Even the **getInstances()** method from the connection object return a **ResultSet** object and not an instances list.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After initially requesting spot instances using the `request_spot_instances` method, you need to then monitor the progress of your request by periodically calling `get_all_spot_instance_requests` to see if your request has been fulfilled.  For example, this call:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
fulfilled = conn.get_all_spot_instance_requests(filters={'status-code': 'fulfilled'})
```

Would return a list of spot instance requests that have been fulfilled.  Each of the `SpotInstanceRequest` objects in that list will have an attribute called `instance_id` which will be the ID of the instance created by the spot instance request.  To turn that into an Instance object, do something like this:

```
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=fulfilled[0].instance_id)
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
```

The `instance` variable should now be an Instance object representing the instance created in your spot instance requests.

Comment: This code seems outdated. Could you update it using boto3? Thanks!